# Exposing the value of a Lookup relationship's element

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, lookup, contact, html

I have a Lookup in my custom object to a Contact object exposed in Visualforce. The user selects a contact by doing a lookup:

```
<apex:page standardController="Software_Activation__c" extensions="SoftwareActivationController">
    ...
    <apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__c}"/>
    ...
</apex:page>
```

I need to do some AJAX with the `Email` of this `Contact` so I need to expose the contact's email address in HTML somehow. I tried this:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__c.Email}" id="shipToEmail" disabled="true" />
```

However, it didn't work:

> Error: Unknown property 'String.Email'

How can I expose a lookup field's property in my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `Contact__c` is actually just the id field, i.e. it will contain the Id of the Contact and not the actual Contact. Instead, what you want to do is use the reference field `Contact__r`, i.e. `Software_Activation__c.Contact__r.Email` to get the value of the referenced Contact.

Edit: Here you can find a detailed explanation from salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm

Comment: That won't work with `<apex:inputField>`.

Comment: Is there a natural way to populate the `shipToEmail`'s value automatically when a lookup for a `Contact` happens if I use `Contact__r`?

Comment: Follow-up question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171349/populating-fields-once-a-lookup-is-selected