# Populating fields once a lookup is selected

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, lookup, contact, html

I have a `Contact` lookup that the user selects:

```
<apex:page standardController="Software_Activation__c" extensions="SoftwareActivationController">
    ...
    <apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__c}"/>
    <apex:inputText id="shipToEmail" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__r.Email}" disabled="true" />
    ...
</apex:page>
```

As you can see, I also expose the email (`Software_Activation__c.Contact__r.Email`) of this `Contact`. But, there is a problem. I thought this would work to set the `value` of the `inputText` once a `Contact` is selected via the lookup `inputField`, but it is not set automatically. It is only set when I load my page with the contact (`Software_Activation__c.Contact__c`) already set.

How can I populate the `inputText`'s value automatically when a lookup for a `Contact` happens?

**Edit**: I have tried the following but it does not update the value of the `inputText` field:

```
<apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ContactSelected}" reRender="shipToEmail" />
</apex:inputField>
<apex:inputText value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__r.Email}" id="shipToEmail" disabled="true" />
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class SoftwareActivationController {

    private final Software_Activation__c activation;

    public SoftwareActivationController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        controller.addFields(new List<String>{'Activation_ID__c'});
        activation = (Software_Activation__c)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference ContactSelected() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to update the value in your controller and rerender that section once the Contact is selected. On load the reference is null to the `shiptoemail` is null and it does not update automatically as you have found

Comment: @Eric Yes, but how? What is the standard way of doing this in Visualforce / Apex?

Comment: Use an `actionSupport` that executes a method in your apex controller to update the values and then use the `rerender` property of the `actionSupport` to rerender the parent element. We would need to see the "ContactSelected" method in your controller as well as how you are instantiating the contact in your controller

Comment: @Eric I have added my controller method. I am not sure how it should be instantiated in this case, so for sure I must be missing something. I just assumed that (from my web development experience) it would automatically present the correct data from when the contact is selected. But if that is not the case, could you show me how to instantiate it please?

Comment: your method does nothing so I am not sure what you expected. See me answer for a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I quickly worked up:

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="mytestClass">
    <apex:form id="theFrm">
    <apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Contact.AccountId}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!accountSelected}" rerender="theFrm"/>
    </apex:inputField>
    <apex:inputText id="shipToEmail" value="{!Contact.Account.Name}" disabled="true" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myTestClass{

    private ApexPages.StandardController internalCon;

    public mytestClass(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        internalCon = con;
    }

    public void accountSelected(){
        Contact c = (Contact)internalCon.getRecord();
        Account a = [Select Id, Name From Account where Id = :c.AccountId];

        c.Account = a;

    }


}
```

Basically, assign the standard controller to a private property so it can be manipulated later.

Then on selection of the Account, query the account and set the contact.Account to the account.

No error handling included and there may be better ways but it works

**Using your object**

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Software_Activation__c" extensions="mytestClass">
    <apex:form id="theFrm">
    <apex:inputField id="contact" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!contactSelected}" rerender="theFrm"/>
    </apex:inputField>
    <apex:inputText id="shipToEmail" value="{!Software_Activation__c.Contact__r.Email}" disabled="true" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class myTestClass{

    private ApexPages.StandardController internalCon;

    public mytestClass(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        internalCon = con;
    }

    public void contactSelected(){
        Software_Activation__c sa = (Software_Activation__c)internalCon.getRecord();
        Contact c = [Select Id, Email From Contact where Id = :sa.Contact__c];

        sa.Contact__r = c;

    }


}
```

Comment: You're exampling a different use case applied to a standard controller, but my controller is an extension which makes things a lot trickier. Now I'm stuck as how to get the contact ID.

Comment: @Alexandru - I do not have the objects you do. My example uses a controller extension as well. The concepts are the same regardless of object. You have a standard controller as well....

Comment: Erm, sorry, I meant, I am using a custom object with a lookup to a contact and not a standard object like Contact, and that's what makes it tricky.

Comment: @Alexandru - Just replace the object and relationship names. Do the above example in isolation from the rest of your code, get it to work with your custom object, then go from there when you understand what it is doing

Comment: I am trying to do that but its not as easy as one would guess. :(

Comment: @Alexandru - There, did it for you

Comment: Many thanks, Eric. This one went a long way in my technical development for Visualforce!

Comment: @Alexandru - Great. Important to note then that you should notice how the StandardController is all "by reference" in a way. Thats why we set it on instantiation so we can modify it within the class as needed. Removes the need to created other properties etc to work on and keeps things simple.